# SSL issue in Joomla web site

Tags: joomla, https

We have installed SSL in server for a Joomla website and https is working fine for Joomla admin panel. But in front end it auto redirecting to http.
i.e in browser if I enter https://mysite.com it auto redirect to http://mysite.com (without S).

I do not know how to fix this. Please help me.

Joomla version - 2.5.7

Comment: check http://joomlawebhosting.ca/joomla-15-tips/63-joomla-ssl-https-setup.html hope its help you to resolved this

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following instructions are for Joomla 3, but for other versions the instructions should be identical, it will just look a bit different and the menus might be in a different place.

1. Log into your Joomla admin site.
2. Go to Global Configuration
3. Go to the Server tab.
4. Find the option "Force SSL" and change it to "Entire Site".
5. Click "Save and Close"
6. Clear your site cache.
7. If you have any SEF extensions with caches, they will need their caches purged too. They may also have their own HTTPS settings within their configuration, however that will vary by extension.

Here is a screenshot taken from Joomla 3:

[image: Screen capture illustrating the location of required actions in Joomla 3]

It is also possible to activate SSL on a per-page basis. This is done via the menu manager.

You may also want to check your web server configuration (i.e. .htaccess) for any rewrites or redirects, but that's beyond the scope of Joomla configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion. (1)If I set "Entire Site" then it throws "The page isn't redirecting properly". (2) I tried this option for About us page, when mouse over the menu it shows https:// but click on it, it goes to http:// (3)I renamed the .htaccess in FTP. All the 3 options are not working.

Also I disable the redirect plugin and empty the records of redirect component.

Comment: In <root>/index.php I used php "exit;" after "$app->initialise();". then I checked in https://mysite.com, the browser stops execution at the line. Then I removed the "exit;" command and added after "$app->route();" and then checked in the browser - https://mysite.com andit is redirect to http://mysite.com. So somewhere in Joomla it redirect to http:// during $app->route();
please help me how to check this. Thanks.

Comment: I removed unused components and plugins, Now it is working fine. Thanks to all.